# Convert list with a for

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
pin_configuration = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [...]]
bool_list = [[False] * 68] * 68

for m in range(0, 68):
    for b in range(0, len(pin_configuration[m][1:])):
        position = pin_configuration[m][b]
        bool_list[m][position] = True
```

Now I have a output like this:

```
bool_list = [[True, False, False,False,...], [True, False, False, 
False,...], [True, False, False, False,...], [...]
```

But i want this:

```
bool_list = [[True, False, False,False,...], [False, True, False, 
False,...], [False, False, True, False,...], [...]
```

I just want to set True in bool_list there where the value pin_configuration[x][1] is
How I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get the desired list. Just set `n` back to 68 once you're sure it works fine.
You need to create `n` distinct lists first, and you can then iterate over the `pin_configuration` coordinates to set the desired elements to `True`.

Note that the first element in Python lists has index `0`, not `1`:

```
pin_configuration = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]

n = 5
bool_list = [[False] * n for i in range(n)]

for i,j in pin_configuration:
    bool_list[i-1][j-1] = True

print(bool_list)
#[[True, False, False, False, False], [False, True, False, False, False], [False, False, True, False, False], [False, False, False, True, False], [False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Comment: What if I have now this: `pin_configuration = [[1, 1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 3, 1], [4, 4]]`

Answer (score 4):

You initialize bool_list in wrong way - instead of making 68 separate lists (rows), you make 68 references to the same list.

```
bool_list = [[False] * 68 for i in range(68)]
```

will do what you want.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `bool_list = [[False] * 68 for i in range(68)]`

Comment: @np.array thanks, I was looking for that typo and still not seeing. Need some caffeine, I guess.